# Modify schema of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

What is the simplest way to modify schema of an existing stored procedure in Sql Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `ALTER SCHEMA` to change the schema to your stored procedure without re-creating it:

```
ALTER SCHEMA newSchema TRANSFER oldSchema.yourStoredProcedure
```